# shell script to filter input variables and cut as per the requirement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a requirement where 2 different repo names come such as app-na-repo1 and wcm-repo2. I need to cut the initials of both repo and assign the rest to say as domain.
i.e.

```
repo=app-na-repo1-com-test or wcm-repo2-com-test
```

and with commands I need to filter it and cut it and assign to domain

such as final output should be any of this repo irrespective of the inputs

```
domain=repo1-com-test or repo2-com-test
```

tried several things, but not working out. Any help would be appreciated.
We cut as per below, but how to setup the initial filter, tried if else but not working as can't filter

```
domain=$(echo "$repo" | cut -c8-)

domain=$(echo "$repo" | cut -c4-)
```

Comment: You can learn regex with https://regexcrossword.com/ . Then you can write a regex to match the input, learn about backreferences and use `sed` to match and substitute the line.

Comment: Thanks will definitely do, I am very new to regex and trying to learn. thanks for sharing the regex site details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to delete the two fixed strings, you can use `sed` as demonstrated in

```
for repo in 'app-na-repo1-com-test' 'wcm-repo2-com-test'; do
  printf "%-30s => " "${repo}"
  sed -r 's/^(app-na-)|(wcm-)//g' <<< "${repo}"
done
```

Result:

```
app-na-repo1-com-test          => repo1-com-test
wcm-repo2-com-test             => repo2-com-test
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for, domain=$(sed -r 's/^(app-na-)|(wcm-)//g' <<< "${repo}"), passing this is giving me my output. Appreciate your help here.

Comment: When you want to remome the `com-` from the result, you can use `domain=$(sed -r 's/^(app-na-)|(wcm-)//g; s/([^-]*).*-(.*)/\1-\2/'' <<< "${repo}")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "app-na-repo1/wcm-repo2" | sed -e 's/[^\/]*-//g'
repo1/repo2
```

Comment: Thanks but what if the string is app-na-repo1-test-com and I just need repo1-com, I really very new to regex, sorry for one more question. My issue is that it should remove only app-na- and wcm- and rest whatever part is left that should get print

Comment: regex will not work in this case, domains may have diffrent levels like `sub-abc-com` `abc-com`